# Rails Performance Profile Reports 0 MB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm experiencing unexpected behavior when I try to do some performance testing. It's always reporting 0 MB memory even though millions of objects are created in the run. While the profiler is running, Activity Monitor is reporting memory usage in the 100s of MB.

Here are some details about my local environment:

- OS: Mac OS 10.9.5
- Hardware: MacBook Air
- Ruby: 2.2.2 (RVM)
- Rails: 4.1.11 using
- rails-perftest & ruby-prof gems

Any idea why I'm seeing zero memory usage?

```sh
$ RAILS_ENV=development perftest profiler 'Queue.last.refill' -m process_time,memory,objects,gc_runs,gc_time
Run options: --seed 30468

# Running:

ProfilerTest#test_queue_last_refill (10.00 sec warmup)
        process_time: 62.34 sec
              memory: 0 Bytes
             objects: 3,903,787
             gc_runs: 3
             gc_time: 0 ms
.

Finished in 239.965591s, 0.0042 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the GC patched MRI. You also need to require ruby-prof.
Check the documentation here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html#installing-gc-patched-mri

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm using Rails 4.1 with Ruby 2.2.2 (I updated the question to make that point more clear), so it doesn't look like that documentation is relevant to my problem, unless I'm missing something.

This is from the rails-perftest documentation: https://github.com/rails/rails-perftest#installing-gc-patched-mri-1xx